# Selenium "Select" Class returns "Unsupported locator strategy" error

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to enter a website using Python and it's Selenium Package. In this website I have to: (1) enter some login credentials (2) go to a specific page (need the credentials to travel there)
(3) select value from drop-down list

I have managed the first two steps, however, I can't manage to overcome the drop-down list problem. I always get the error:

```
Message: invalid argument: Unsupported locator strategy: null
```

I have tried to change my Locator method from "name" to "id" and to "value" but have been unsuccessful.

Any assistance would be much appreciated, I am puzzled as to why all the rest works and this specific point fails. I can't provide the original website as example due to proprietary issues.

Thank you!

EDIT: I have added the HTML code regarding the drop-down list, had to omit some information due to personal details but I think it should help anyways.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

#log-in info
userStr = "User"
passStr = 'Pass'

#enter log-in
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('https://www.example.com'))

Log_User = browser.find_element_by_id('user_field')
Log_User.send_keys(userStr)

Log_User = browser.find_element_by_id('pass_field')
Log_User.send_keys(passStr)

Enter_Button = browser.find_element_by_id('enter_button')
Enter_Button.click()

#go to desired window
browser.get(('https://www.example.com/newpage.aspx'))

#select dropdown (the issue is here)
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('drop-down-list'))
select.select_by_value("target")
```

```html
<div class="ms-webpart-zone ms-fullWidth">
    <div id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2" class="s4-wpcell-plain ms-webpartzone-cell ms-webpart-cell-vertical ms-fullWidth ">
        <div class="ms-webpart-chrome ms-webpart-chrome-vertical ms-webpart-chrome-fullWidth ">
            <div webpartid="46ca13d8-6d03-474f-bc6c-d2c6cf8c95f2" haspers="false" id="WebPartWPQ2" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody noindex " allowdelete="false" style=""><div class="ms-rtestate-field"><h2 class="3s-web-title">***<br></h2></div><div class="ms-clear"></div></div>
        </div><div class="ms-PartSpacingVertical"></div>
    </div><div id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartctl00_ctl51_g_0c672ab8_73ff_4b46_a925_3f0c0213b64d" class="s4-wpcell-plain ms-webpartzone-cell ms-webpart-cell-vertical ms-fullWidth ">
        <div class="ms-webpart-chrome ms-webpart-chrome-vertical ms-webpart-chrome-fullWidth ">
            <div webpartid="0c672ab8-73ff-4b46-a925-3f0c0213b64d" haspers="false" id="WebPartctl00_ctl51_g_0c672ab8_73ff_4b46_a925_3f0c0213b64d" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody noindex " allowdelete="false" style=""><div style="display: table; margin-bottom: 10px;"><div style="display: table-row;"><div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;"><label style="margin-bottom: 0px;" for="ctl00_ctl51_g_0c672ab8_73ff_4b46_a925_3f0c0213b64d_ddlDealers">Concessionário:</label></div><div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: left; padding-left: 15px;">
            <select name="ctl00$ctl51$g_0c672ab8_73ff_4b46_a925_3f0c0213b64d$ddlDealers" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ctl51$g_0c672ab8_73ff_4b46_a925_3f0c0213b64d$ddlDealers\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ctl51_g_0c672ab8_73ff_4b46_a925_3f0c0213b64d_ddlDealers">
                <option selected="selected" value="-1;-1">-- Concessionário --</option>
                <option value="*****;****">***** (Special Sales) (****2)</option>
        ...
        </select></div></div></div>
            <span>Necessita de seleccionar um concessionário.</span><div class="ms-clear"></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

is find_element_by_name really a thing? You can do:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[name="drop-down-list"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to be complaining about a null argument passed into the constructor for `Select`. My guess would be `browser.find_element_by_name('drop-down-list')` is not returning anything, which could set the value to `null`, and that's what the error message might be detailing.

Based on the HTML you provided, it doesn't look like your locator for the `select` element is correct -- you are searching `by_name`, but the element does not have a distinct `name` attribute -- it is just a randomly generated string.

I tested your code in my browser and I received a `NoSuchElementException` when `browser.find_element_by_name('drop-down-list')` did not find an element, so I'm not sure where the `null` error is coming from. `select_by_value` just takes a `string` parameter, so I don't think the issue is on that line either.

You could try changing to an XPath and see if that works:

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[contains(@id, 'ddlDealers')]"))
```

Since you mentioned there is only one `select` element on the page, you could also try:

```
# locate select element
select_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select")

# call print to verify something has been located
print(select_element) 

# declare the select object
select = Select(select_element)
```

Something like `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="5c7855ef72bf6bca9babb1e0a7a22ac2", element="6e100df3-342d-47ad-99f3-f48300282b5b")>` will print in the console if an element has successfully been located -- this will rule out whether or not the issue is with the selector.

If this does not work, there may be some sort of `iframe` element that is hiding the `select` from driver -- if the above code throws a `NoSuchElementException`, we may need to see some more HTML on the page to get the context which the `select` appears in.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have tried you approach but the error remains the same. I have tried running the code without the  `select_by_value` and the error remain so I have to agree with your thoughts on this. Perhaps the issue is that I shouldn't be using the Select class, I have followed you advise and shared some of the webpage's code so that you or other users can give their opinions regarding that.

Comment: The first issue I see from the HTML is that your `select` element does not actually have a distinct `name` identifier. So your `find_element` on the `select` will not return anything. I've modified my solution with a possible path that may locate the correct element and fix this issue.

Comment: I have just finished testing your suggestion and the problem remains, I have also tested simply trying to change the locator `Select(browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl51_g_0c672ab8_73ff_4b46_a925_3f0c0213b64d_ddlDealers"))` but I still get the same error message. Is it possible to use the class as a locator? It is the only drop-down list on the page so there wouldn't be the risk of a wrong match.

Comment: Yes, you could change it to just `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select")`. If there is just one `select` on the page, this will find it. I would try to just run the `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select")` statement on its own (outside of the `Select()` declaration) to make sure an element can actually be located. Then, you can place the statement in the `Select()` declaration like in your sample code. I've updated my answer with the example at the end.

Comment: The issues continue. I'm wondering if this could be about the webpage and not the drop-down list. On the page there is also a Box for text input, I tried locating it with a locator and got the same issue. This made me wonder if the page was not fullly loaded when trying to run the locators and therefore it couldn't find anything, but even with a `time.sleep` command it will not work. I think I will have to replace the second `browser.get` on the middle of the code with something else, i believe jumping to another window might be the problem. Anyways thank you very much for your all your time.

Comment: Feel free to post another question with some of the issues you are experiencing. For waiting, I recommend using the `WebDriverWait` class rather than `time.sleep`. It’s alao possible there are other elements on the page that are interfering with the select element. A link to the web page you are trying to automate might help as well.